# Flutter: Black area above debug banner

Tags: flutter

I have a problem for a while.

Idon't know why, but I have black area that cover my debug banner.

This black area reduce height of my app.
I try to replace the content with blanc container but nothing.
I try also to inspect area but nothing.

I have the app on playstore. When I download it from play store, black area still there (large black area on top and small on bottom of the app).

[image]

Do you have what can be the issue and how can I solve it please?

Thanks (very sort for my English)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`SafeArea`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html):

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: …
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already put this in my home screen code.

Comment: @Netron90 you need to put the `SafeArea` inside the `Scaffold`, not outside the `Scaffold`

Comment: I also try this, but black screen still there.